# Calculate derivative of integral numerically?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

I want to numerically evaluate the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{d}{d x} g(x) \\
g(x) &= \int_a^b h(x,y)dy
\end{align}
$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ some continous function.

What would be an efficient way to approach this? I know I can use some kind of ode-solver to numerically evaluate a definite integral of a single variable, but how to deal with the derivative and the second variable?

Comment: So $f(x) = \int_a^b \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x,y)\,dy$.  Numerically estimate the derivative in one direction, the integral in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting the second equation into the first,
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^b h(x,y)dy$$
And by the Leibniz Integral rule,
$$f(x)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial }{\partial x}h(x,y)dy$$
So if you were trying to evaluate $f(x_0)$, then 
$$f(x_0)=\int_a^b\frac{\partial }{\partial x}h(x,y)\bigg|_{x=x_0} dy$$
$$f(x_0)=\int_a^b h^{*}(y)dy$$
Which is of course just a constant. Is this the sort of answer you wanted? Tell me what I can do to better answer your question.